# Custom URL structure for wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have two Custom Post type,

```
register_post_type( 'classes', 
    array(
        .
        .
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'classes', 'with_front' => false )
    ) 
);

register_post_type( 'lessons', 
    array(
        .
        .
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'chapters', 'with_front' => false )
    ) 
);
```

I have created a custom admin UI to manage (create/update/delete) this two post type, the lesson post type is design to be a child post type for classes post type. So everytime someone create a lesson, it requires a parent post from the list of post type classes.

Now I have a problem with the url structure,

the URL of the classes will be `site.dev/classes/class-post-name`

and the URL of the lesson will be `site.dev/chapters/lesson-post-name` this is also the URL I can i see on wp_posts table under guid column

How can I acheive a URL structure like below that will also be stored as guid?
`site.dev/classes/parent-post-post-name/chapters/lesson-post-name`

Answer (score 0):

[Parent Post From Another Post Type and a new URL structure](https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/) will help in achieving the results. The `lessons` post type should be **hierarchical** and `classes` should be **non-hierarchical**. One thing is notable in the metabox that you don't need to save the metabox manually. WordPress itself checks for field name `parent_id` and saves it.

Comment: I have similar set-up with the rewrite rule mentioned from that post, but the problem with the rule ```lesson/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?``` is that the first parameter is being ignored and not validated as a "VALID PARENT POST" so you can put anything in there and would still display the lesson

Comment: @SymmetricsWeb Did you deactivate and activate the permalinks from Settings > Permalinks

Comment: You need to add check on both `index.php?course=$match[1]&lesson=$matches[2]` . So it validates both parameters.